# CAKE PHP 3 - query with OR on object or related object

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, associations, query-builder

I am wondering how to do a specific query in cakephp 3 -

I am trying to figure out how to do a where with OR but the where is on the object im working with, and the OR is on a relation..

This query works, if $user_id is the owner of the event...

```
$query = $this->Events
    ->find('all')
    ->limit(1)
    ->where([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'Events.id' => $id
    ])
    ->contain([
        'Users',
        'Groups'
    ]);
```

But, what if I also want to query if the above is successful, OR one of the USERS relations has an id equal to $user_id ? I have read and tried many things, but can not seem to find an option that would work.. ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: Whenever asking questions that involve associations, please always include the association configuration details! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!